# How does "<<" operator work in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I know the following code creates a file core-site.xml in the /opt/hadoop/conf directory. Can some one please break it down in linux shell terms for me?  Especially the << operator & CORE_EOF? How does those markers work? I kind of understand this but wanted to know better.

```
cat >/opt/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml <<CORE_EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
CORE_EOF
```

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html it is a "HEREDOC".

Comment: This is called a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). Which part of it don't you understand.

Comment: @larsmans The part that involved looking in the manual I suspect ;-)

Comment: @pst is correct, my bad i am so spoiled by google search. I didn't know what it is called .. "here doc". I didn't lookup the bash manual, the first place i should have gone to. thanks for the links.

Answer (score 25):

A command with the << operator will do the following things :

- Launch the program specified in the left of the operator, cat for instance.
- Grab user input, including newlines, until what is specified on the right of the operator is met on one line, EOF for instance
- Send all that have been read except the EOF value to the standard input of the program on the left.

  ```
  cat << EOF
  Hello
  World
  EOF
  ```

Will send "Hello

World"

To the standard input of cat.

It is the same as doing this:

```
cat < file
```

With file containing :

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cat** make a new file or rewrite old with same name in this condition

and put your string into file.

When you want to add strings into file 
type this:

> cat **>>** /opt/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml << EOF
>
> String
>
> String
>
> EOF